# Generate unique Form URL for each respondent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google [Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1vsqvwomoqSXwF6TlNkmmktAAk2av2r-2LRrBYJdv3VQ/viewform) With a Google spreadsheet to store responses. In my spread sheet I have 4 columns: name, email, revenue, and a fourth column, Id, which is used to identify the particular recipient.

What I am trying to accomplish is to generate a unique URL for each respondent so that they can respond to the form **and** use the same URL to edit the form at a later time.

I've looked at the `getEditUrl()` (Google Apps Script) method which creates a unique URL for the respondent *after* submitting the response-- code below:

```
function myFunction() {
  assignEditUrls();  
}

function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1vsqvwomoqSXwF6TlNkmmktAAk2av2r-2LRrBYJdv3VQ');
    //enter form ID here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');

    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 5; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) { 
    var resp = responses[i];

    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(shortenUrl(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl()));
    withItemResponse(responses[i])
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    var dop = data[j][0]

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]: '']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}


function shortenUrl(longUrl) {
  // google url shortener api key
  var key = "AIzaSyBVG4Q5i1mNI0YAO0XVGZ3suZU8etTvK34";

  var serviceUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key="+key;

  var options={
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    method:"post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload : JSON.stringify({'longUrl': longUrl })
  };

  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);

  if(response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    if ( (content != null) && (content["id"] != null) )
      return content["id"];
  }

  return longUrl;
}
```

However I want to do it the other way which is to first generate the unique URL to be then sent to respondents so they can submit and edit their responses without the need of sending them another URL (e.g. the `editurlresponse`).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you want to know who submitted the form?  Have you looked at how the pre-filled url is constructed?  You can construct a "pre-filled" url (a url that fills in some or all of the fields).  For example, you could construct a pre-filled url, that filled in an item that was the name of the person submitting the form.

Comment: not who responded. I want to build a unique url for each recipient so that they can use that url to submit then re-edit their response.

Comment: This question was cross-posted by another user to the Web Apps SE site:  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86396/88163

Comment: There is an error in the third paragraph. It says "getEditUrl" but this method return the URL to edit the form, not the one to edit a response. See [getEditUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getediturl).

Comment: I'm having this problem... But this code did'nt helped.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86399/88163

---

Yes, it's possible, but with slight different approach:

Submit one answer for each respondent in order to get one edit URL by each of them, then send the corresponding URL to each respondent.

Below is a code snippet that programmatically submits a response and log some response attributes including the edit response url by through two code lines, the first one has an issue, the second one is a workaround. Please note that these lines use `getEditResponseUrl()` not the `toPrefilledUrl()`.

It will work as a stand alone or as a bounded script.

```
/*
This code shows how to get the edit response url of a 
programmatically submitted response to a Google Form
*/ 

// Replace the form ID by your own form
var formID = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  var response = form.createResponse();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var item = items[0];
  if (item.getType() == 'TEXT') {
    var textItem = item.asTextItem();
    var itemResponse = textItem.createResponse('my text');
    response.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
  } 
  // Submit response
  var submittedResponse = response.submit();
  // Get submitted response attributes
  var values = {
    ID : submittedResponse.getId(),
    TS : submittedResponse.getTimestamp(),
    /* 
    Issue 4476: FormApp: getEditResponseUrl() produces invalid URL 
    https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4476
    */
    ER1 : submittedResponse.getEditResponseUrl(),
    /* Workaround from 
    https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4476#c2
    */
    ER2 : submittedResponse.getEditResponseUrl().replace(
      /\?edit2=.*/,"?edit2=" + submittedResponse.getId()
    ) 
  };
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

**References**

- [Class FormResponse - Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [Issue 4476: FormApp: getEditResponseUrl() produces invalid URL](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4476)

Comment: This does not do what the OP requested; while there will be a unique URL for them, it would need to be regenerated any time they submitted the form.

Comment: @Mogsdad : I think that you confused the getEditResponseUrl() with toPrefilledUrl(). The code use the first one.

Comment: You're almost right, I did a different wrong-headed thing - I misremembered how getEditResponseUrl() worked, thinking it tracked the specific values of the response.

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks for coming back. Any tip/suggestions to on how to improve this answer?

Comment: It's a pretty good answer, really. The only things I can suggest is to change the tone from "no, it's not possible" to "yes, but indirectly, here's how", and add a brief summary of what getEditResponseUrl() is _supposed_ to do. The details of having to work around a long-time bug are important for implementing working code, but not for understanding the basic thought process in the solution, so presenting the workaround as a secondary issue could help readers "get it".

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I very rarely start a conversation with a "No", but somewhere I read that it's encouraged to answer with a "No..." followed by an "instead do..." in similar cases :)

Comment: Hello. What does ER1 and ER2 means?

Comment: @RaulChiarella They are property names. They hold two values derived from the edit response URL.